# Error compiling Mosquitto 1.4.8 with libwebsockets

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, mqtt, mosquitto, libwebsockets

After I installed libwebsockets 1.4, I wanted to make Mosquitto 1.4.8 run witch Websockets. But when I compile I get some Errors:

> user@Mate:~/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8$ make
>
> set -e; for d in lib client src; do make -C ${d}; done
>
> make[1]: Entering directory
>    »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/lib«
>
> make -C cpp
>
> make[2]: Entering directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/lib/cpp«
>
> make[2]: Nothing to do for target »all«.
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/lib/cpp«
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/lib«
>
> make[1]: Entering directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/client«
>
> make[1]: Nothing to do for target »all«.
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/client«
>
> make[1]: Entering directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/src«
>
> cc mosquitto.o bridge.o conf.o context.o database.o
>   logging.o loop.o memory_mosq.o persist.o net.o net_mosq.o
>   read_handle.o read_handle_client.o read_handle_server.o
>   read_handle_shared.o security.o security_default.o send_client_mosq.o
>   send_mosq.o send_server.o service.o subs.o sys_tree.o time_mosq.o
>   tls_mosq.o util_mosq.o websockets.o will_mosq.o -o mosquitto  -ldl -lm
>   -lrt -Wl,--dynamic-list=linker.syms -lssl -lcrypto -luuid -lwebsockets loop.o:
>
> In function 'do_disconnect':
>
> /home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/src/loop.c:404:
>   undefined reference to `lws_callback_on_writable' loop.o:
>
> In function 'mosquitto_main_loop':
>   /home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/src/loop.c:378:
>    undefined reference to `lws_service'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[1]: *** [mosquitto] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory »/home/user/Dokumente/mosquitto-1.4.8/src«
>
> make: *** [mosquitto] Error 2

Information: 
I tested Mosquitto two days before without Websockets and it worked well but when I want to compile it again (no matter if I choose Websockets or not) I get these Errors.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your websocket library is not correctly installed.

Try it :

> sudo apt-get install libwebsockets-dev

Comment: ../lib/libcurl-7.56.0/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `RTMP_Write'
../lib/libcurl-7.56.0/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `RTMP_SetBufferMS'
../lib/libcurl-7.56.0/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `RTMP_Free'
../lib/libcurl-7.56.0/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `RTMP_Read'
../lib/libcurl-7.56.0/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `RTMP_Alloc'